# Spark Job crash due to File Not found when shuffle intermittently

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I have several Spark jobs including both batch job and Stream jobs to process the system log and analyze them. We are using Kafka as the pipeline to connect each jobs.

Once upgrade to Spark 2.1.0 + Spark Kafka Streaming 010, I found some of the jobs(both batch or streaming) are thrown below exceptions randomly(either after several hours run or just run in 20 mins). Can anyone give me some suggestions about how to figure out the real root cause? (Looks like there are many posts are discussing this, but the solution seems not very useful for me...)

Is this due to Spark configuration issue or code bug? I can not paste all my jobs codes as there are too much.

> 00:30:04,510 WARN  - 17/07/22 00:30:04 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 60.0 in stage 1518490.0 (TID 338070, 10.133.96.21, executor 0): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/mesos/work_dir/slaves/20160924-021501-274760970-5050-7646-S2/frameworks/40aeb8e5-e82a-4df9-b034-8815a7a7564b-2543/executors/0/runs/fd15c15d-2511-4f37-a106-27431f583153/blockmgr-a0e0e673-f88b-4d12-a802-c35643e6c6b2/33/shuffle_2090_60_0.index.b66235be-79be-4455-9759-1c7ba70f91f6 (No such file or directory)
>   00:30:04,510 WARN  -     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
>   00:30:04,510 WARN  -     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
>   00:30:04,510 WARN  -     at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)
>   00:30:04,510 WARN  -     at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:162)
>   00:30:04,510 WARN  -     at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockResolver.writeIndexFileAndCommit(IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala:144)
>   00:30:04,510 WARN  -     at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:128)
>   00:30:04,510 WARN  -     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
>   00:30:04,510 WARN  -     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
>   00:30:04,510 WARN  -     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
>   00:30:04,510 WARN  -     at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
>   00:30:04,510 WARN  -     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   00:30:04,510 WARN  -     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   00:30:04,510 WARN  -     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause finally. There is no problem with Spark Jobs at all.
We have a crontab which wrong clean up the temp storage at /mnt and wrongly delete the spark cache files.