# Spark is not able to find its own temporary files after some time of running and give java.io.FileNotFound Exception

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

**Problem** 
=========== 
Spark application written in java, streaming a series of data(using ZeroMQ) in batch interval of 2 sec.
The application runs fine for sometime like 10 to 15 days, but after that **java.io.FileNotFound** exception occurs and the spark metrics check fails which leads to spark restart.
Can someone tell me the possible root cause and solution to this problem, Any help is appreciated. 
**Exception** 
=============

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 3422167.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 3422167.0 (TID 22562969, localhost): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/spark/tmp/spark-e9c78b64-7726-406e-bdf5-c50a7696ef70/spark-21c01186-e0cc-4ae0-81a4-3e4a2288bec5/spark-ecb21d84-a891-494c-8a79-744ca5d4a423/blockmgr-010997d1-872b-42ce-8ae9-bbb4b38daa19/0c/shuffle_1006550_1_0.index (No such file or directory)
         at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
         at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
         at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
           at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
           at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockManager.writeIndexFile(IndexShuffleBlockManager.scala:85)
           at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:72)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   Driver stacktrace:
   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 3422167.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 3422167.0 (TID 22562969, localhost): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/spark/tmp/spark-e9c78b64-7726-406e-bdf5-c50a7696ef70/spark-21c01186-e0cc-4ae0-81a4-3e4a2288bec5/spark-ecb21d84-a891-494c-8a79-744ca5d4a423/blockmgr-010997d1-872b-42ce-8ae9-bbb4b38daa19/0c/shuffle_1006550_1_0.index (No such file or directory)
           at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
           at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
           at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
           at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
           at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockManager.writeIndexFile(IndexShuffleBlockManager.scala:85)
           at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:72)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   Driver stacktrace:
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1204)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1193)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
           at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
           at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
           at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

**Configuration** 
================= 
Spark Version: **1.3.1** 
1 Worker (4 cores, 2GB of memory) 
Executor (3 cores and 1GB of memory) 
Driver (1 cores, 1 GB of memory) 
**spark.local.dir** set to **/storage/spark/tmp**

Comment: See also this similar question (and answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825569/spark-worker-throws-filenotfoundexception-on-temporary-shuffle-files

Comment: Also, you are using a very old version of Spark; if you cannot find any other root cause, it may be worth upgrading in case you are encountering a Spark bug.

Comment: See also: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16643

Comment: Another potential cause here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45257840/spark-job-crash-due-to-file-not-found-when-shuffle-intermittently